# Yii2 How to modify file validator for new extension type?

Tags: php, yii2, mime-types, yii2-advanced-app

I have file with extension .edoc and mimetype is application/zip. When I try to upload files with this extension, file validator gives me a standard error - that only given (in rules) extensions is possible to upload. Here is my rules:

```
return array_merge($parent_rules,[
            [
                ['file'],
                'file',
                'maxSize' => 5242880,  // limit 5mb => 5(mb) * 1024(kb) * 1024(b)

                'extensions' => ['pdf','doc','docx','xls','xlsx','png','jpeg','jpg','gif','tiff','tif','avi','flv',
                'wmv','mov','mp4','mkv','ogg','xml','zip','rar','7z','ods','odt','txt','edoc','msg'],
            ],
        ]);
```

I found that in vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\mimeTypes.php there is an array of rules where extension ".edoc" is not described. When I added key=>value pair

```
'edoc' => 'application/zip'
```

File upload is working.

How/is its possible to modify or add this rule without modifying vendor files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Michal Hynčica in first answer gave me a good start for this problem, but for avoid load modified file in memory on every request in the sytem, I modified a little bit his code.

So... I made my own magic file like Michal

```
<?php
// load mime types from original magic file
$originalMagicFile = Yii::getAlias('@yii/helpers/mimeTypes.php');
$mimeTypes = require $originalMagicFile;

$mimeTypes['edoc'] => 'application/zip';
return $mimeTypes;
```

Then I created custom behavior class for this custom magic file

```
class MimeTypesBehavior extends Behavior
{
    public function events(): array
    {
        return [
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE => 'beforeValidate',
        ];
    }

    public function beforeValidate()
    {
        FileHelper::$mimeMagicFile = dirname(__DIR__, 2) .'/backend/models/edocMimeTypes.php';
    }

}
```

and added this behavior to my model form

```
class FileForm extends File
{
    public $file;

    public function behaviors(): array
    {
        return [
            MimeTypesBehavior::class,
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        $parent_rules = parent::rules();
        return array_merge($parent_rules,[
            [
                ['file'],
                'file',
                'maxSize' => 5242880,  //  limit 5mb => 5(mb) * 1024(kb) * 1024(b)
                'extensions' => ['pdf','doc','docx','xls','xlsx','png','jpeg','jpg','gif','tiff','tif','avi','flv',
                    'wmv','mov','mp4','mkv','ogg','xml','zip','rar','7z','ods','odt','txt','edoc','msg']
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

And everything works perfect.

Comment: As I've explained in comment below my answer the modified magic file is not loaded before each request. Only `FileHelper` is loaded to set its static property. On the other side your solution has 2 major flaws. Every time you will need to use file validator you will have to remember to include this behavior. Also, this solution can lead to inconsistency. If `FileHelper` is used anywhere before validation it will work with unmodified magic file. If it's used after validation it will work with modified magic file.

Comment: Also you should check how [`FileHelper::loadMimeTypes()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/1f59b72a9dba5339f2e776d37d5c88fac425cfe0/framework/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php#L235) is implemented. If the `loadMimeTypes()` is called and then your validation is run, you will end up with having both modified and unmodified file loaded in `BaseFileHelper::$_mimeTypes` static property.

Answer (score 1):

`yii\validators\FileValidator` uses `yii\helpers\FileHelper` to get list of extensions for mime type. You can tell FileHelper to use different file as mime magic file.

Prepare your own magic file, it can look for example like this:

```php
<?php
// load mime types from original magic file
$originalMagicFile = Yii::getAlias('@yii/helpers/mimeTypes.php');
$mimeTypes = require $originalMagicFile;

$mimeTypes['edoc'] => 'application/zip';
return $mimeTypes;
```

Then you need to tell the file helper to use your magic file instead of original one. To do that you need to set [`yii\helpers\FileHelper::$mimeMagicFile`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper#$mimeMagicFile-detail) static property. It's best to do that in before request event handler. That's when application is already initialized (so you can use aliases) but the request is not being processed yet.

So, add something like this to your config:

```
$config = [
    // ... other app configurations ...

    'on beforeRequest' => function () {
        \yii\helpers\FileHelper::$mimeMagicFile = '/path/to/your/magicFile.php';
        // you can even use aliases, for example:
        //\yii\helpers\FileHelper::$mimeMagicFile = '@app/components/mimeTypes.php';
    }

];
```

Comment: Your answer was a good start for this problem, but there is one thing - this file will be loaded before every request in the system and as I have very big and heavy system it not the best choice. Still thank you, this really helped me and i'l post my modification too

Comment: Only `\yii\helpers\FileHelper` is loaded because we are only setting its static property. The modified magic file is not loaded until `FileHelper` needs it. And loading `FileHelper` in each request shouldn't be issue. It's used by `yii\base\View` to localize view template files so it's loaded  in most requests anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        return array_merge($parent_rules, [
            [
                ['file'],
                'file',
                'maxSize' => 5242880,  // limit 5mb => 5(mb) * 1024(kb) * 1024(b),
                'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false,
                'mimeTypes' => ['application/zip'],
                'extensions' => ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'tiff', 'tif', 'avi', 'flv',
                    'wmv', 'mov', 'mp4', 'mkv', 'ogg', 'xml', 'zip', 'rar', '7z', 'ods', 'odt', 'txt', 'edoc', 'msg'],
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That is bad option to false "checkExtensionByMimeType" because of security.